# Uber API integration | Payment workflow

Tags: uber-api

I am looking to integrate the Uber API in my app. I understand Uber allow to provide the booking option with in the app however is it possible to collect the payment in my own app for the rides? Can I collect the payment in my account, how would I transfer further to Uber, if possible or it would be credited to Uber Only? How the complete payment workflow works from third party applications.

Just wondering if there is any possible way for this and someone has any idea about the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Payment options is only through by cash!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to collect payment directly for Uber Rides. It is against the API terms of service to attempt to collect any per ride fee. See our [affiliate program for more details about earning with the Uber API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/affiliate-program/introduction).