# Uber API to integrate mobile app where app will make uber payment

Tags: payment, uber-api

Is there any API or Service from Uber to integrate with my mobile app so that app users can make travelling expenses along with app services. Then the app can make corresponding amount to uber account in the background. This will help app users to avoid multiple payments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uber API integration | Payment workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095777/uber-api-integration-payment-workflow)

Comment: Uber's documentation is available at developer.uber.com. You might want to look into Uber for Business, but no, I don't believe there is a general way for you to pay for user's rides, the users have to pay directly to Uber.